# Determine the skewness of a gamma distribution with a coefficient of variation of 1.

Tags: statistics

let $\alpha =a$ and $\beta =b$ 
If $X$ follows a gamma dist. then $E[X]=\frac{a}{b}$ and $Var[X]=\frac{a}{b^2}$

how do I prove that the mean is equal to the standard deviation, so the coefficient of variation equals one?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're not being asked to prove that the CV of the gamma distribution is equal to one (which isn't generally the case), but to find the skewness assuming that the CV = 1. Now,

$\text{CV} = \frac{\sigma}{\mu}$,

so if the CV = 1, it should be obvious that $\mu = \sigma$. Now, all you have to do is plug in $a/b$ for $\mu$ and $\sqrt{a/b^2}$ for $\sigma$. Solve for $a$, and then you can use the formula for skewness for the gamma distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)

Answer (score 0):

Coefficient of variation = 1 implies

mean = standard deviation

Or, $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{b}$

Or, $a = 1$ since $a > 0$

Hence skewness $=\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}} = 2$